Uploaded IFormFile is always null
I'm working on a image upload feature for my React Native 0.76.1 application with a .NET 8.0 backend. I am running into issues receiving the IFormFile properly on the backend.
No matter what I do, it seems the IFormFile coming in is always null, even though I can see it being present in HttpContext.Request.Form:

The incoming request also has Content-Type: multipart/form-data header:

Just to be explicit, I've also added the [FromForm] attribute to my API endpoint:
public class JobController : BaseController
{
    private readonly JobService _jobService;

    public JobController(JobService jobService)
    {
        _jobService = jobService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<Guid> AddJobAsync([FromForm] AddJobInputModel model)
    {
        return await _jobService.AddJobAsync(model.AsAddJobModel());
    }
}

The relevant models:
public class AddJobInputModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "WizardIdRequired")]
    public Guid WizardId { get; set; }
    public decimal? CalculatedPrice { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "DetailsRequired")]
    public AddJobDetailInputModel[]? Details { get; set; }

    public AddJobModel AsAddJobModel()
    {
        return new AddJobModel
        {
            WizardId = WizardId,
            CalculatedPrice = CalculatedPrice,
            Details = Details!
                .Select(jd => jd.AsAddJobDetailModel())
                .ToArray()
        };
    }
}

public class AddJobDetailInputModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "FieldIdRequired")]
    public Guid? FieldId { get; set; }

    public string? Value { get; set; }
    
    public IFormFile? FileTest { get; set; }

    public List<IFormFile>? Files { get; set; }

    public AddJobDetailModel AsAddJobDetailModel()
    {
        return new AddJobDetailModel
        {
            FieldId = FieldId!.Value,
            Value = Value,
            File = FileTest
        };
    }
}

All the other fields are binding properly (such as wizardId, details[n].fieldId, details[n].value:

It's just IFormFile that won't bind, and I have no idea why.
If it's relevant, here is a serialized representation of the FormData I'm sending from the front end:
{
    "_parts":[
        [
            "wizardId",
            "ab629ade-0a9c-4f2b-b06c-e23f807d524d"
        ],
        [
            "details[0].fieldId",
            "c1885911-f2fa-42be-9c2c-4a4cc728e9dd"
        ],
        [
            "details[0].value",
            "PostalCode"
        ],
        [
            "details[1].fieldId",
            "56744dd4-a041-4fb5-a92f-15f1114cc804"
        ],
        [
            "details[1].value",
            "123 m2"
        ],
        [
            "details[2].fieldId",
            "4db89fdd-ab44-4187-8dfb-fb080448df47"
        ],
        [
            "details[2].value",
            "6535178c-cdb5-4723-a044-59feca2a5658"
        ],
        [
            "details[3].fieldId",
            "dc8665b1-98c4-481c-ab8c-9a5e04a4996c"
        ],
        [
            "details[3].value",
            "c18458c0-d7f8-4103-8dfc-c039770ce061"
        ],
        [
            "details[4].fieldId",
            "e6b0da98-1424-45b9-bcd9-b0e65d54fa3d"
        ],
        [
            "details[4].value",
            "9fca0a9c-d310-484c-a469-68d2c234c82e"
        ],
        [
            "details[5].fieldId",
            "9f14cf43-bda4-40e6-b356-5f3d6232a267"
        ],
        [
            "details[5].value",
            "1d690725-20e4-4853-9a28-a6cbb76f1102"
        ],
        [
            "details[6].fieldId",
            "81453abf-af63-4c63-b71e-00ce4a161dc6"
        ],
        [
            "details[6].value",
            "Qwer"
        ],
        [
            "details[7].fieldId",
            "6d5905a7-869e-4a9a-b5f1-aa04b6f549ff"
        ],
        [
            "details[7].fileTest.width",
            "800"
        ],
        [
            "details[7].fileTest.fileName",
            "35616D7D-7E64-4C02-8D93-591A380FC699.jpg"
        ],
        [
            "details[7].fileTest.height",
            "533"
        ],
        [
            "details[7].fileTest.type",
            "image/jpg"
        ],
        [
            "details[7].fileTest.uri",
            "file:///Users/bok/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/655A9DE8-190D-4CEF-B14E-DA73E42E33FA/data/Containers/Data/Application/7CFEAEE4-1099-4A84-B801-0FB9EA34D641/tmp/35616D7D-7E64-4C02-8D93-591A380FC699.jpg"
        ],
        [
            "details[7].fileTest.fileSize",
            "132883"
        ]
    ]
}

Thank you for your time.

Are you constructing the object for FileTest your own? Would be great to share your front-end code how you get the file and send the form.

You're not sending a file here, just a path that's local.  Instead, send FormData object from front end.  That'll send a standard form with proper boundaries and stream the file.  It'll also set the proper headers and do everything for you:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData You can create a FormData object from the  element directly.  (it'll automatically include all the fields...)

Here's an example of TS code I use in Angular:   let form = document.getElementById('myForm')! as HTMLFormElement;
let formData = new FormData(form);  (that's for ....)  That's more or less straight up javascript so it should work in React, too.  The only typescript part is the ! and as HTMLFormElement... (not sure if React uses Typescript)
